# How to not executing again Ajax query after popstate

Tags: jquery, html5-history

I have a jquery script to change content of page using pushstate and Ajax.

Right now it works fine but when I go back with the button of browser , the popstate event execute the Ajax query again.

Is it possible to save state and load the previous view without executing Ajax query again ?

I have read about `e.originalEvent.state` into popstate , but I don't know if it can do the same thing or no.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function loadPage(route) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'html',
        url: route,
        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg === undefined) {
                alert('error');
            } else {                    
                $('#content').html(
                    $(msg).find('#content')
                );
            }
        }
    });

}


$(window).on("popstate", function () {
    //This function will always execute Ajax query again
    // but I'd like to not executing  Ajax query again after popstate event
    loadPage(window.location.href);

});

$(document).on('click', ".load-ajax", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var route = $(this).attr('href');

    window.history.pushState(null, "Title", route);

    loadPage(route);

});

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Essentially yes.  You would do it by storing the result of the AJAX in the history object.  Which means you'd have to do the pushState in the return:success of the AJAX call.  Then during popstate you'd read that data out again.

You can pass any object you want to the pushState method, for example here I create an arbitrary object (for hiding and showing divs):

```
lastPageState = { div:divName, pos:amount, page:lastLoadedPage };
history.pushState(lastPageState, divName.substring(1,divName.length-6), "index.html");
```

You would just need to make the `lastPageState` object contain the data returned by the AJAX call.

Something like this:

```
    success: function (msg) {
        if (msg === undefined) {
            alert('error');
        } else {                    
            $('#content').html(
                $(msg).find('#content')
            );
            //new code
            var state = {data:$(msg).find('#content')};
            window.history.pushState(state, "Title", "index.html");
        }
    }
```

...

```
$(window).on("popstate", function () {
    $('#content').html(event.state.data);
});
```

Comment: Sorry , but I didn't understand how to adapt it with my script. I have read about `e.originalEvent.state` into popstate also  , can you tell me if it can do the same thing or no ?

Answer (score 0):

Now my code is like this and popstate works fine **except the initial page** which is loaded regularly not with pushState doesn't work

```
$(window).on("popstate", function () {
    $('#main').html(event.state.data);
});

$(document).on('submit', "#search-form", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //...
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'html',
        beforeSend: function () {
            //...
        },
        success: function (html) {
            console.log('Success');
            //..
            var state = {data: $('#main').html()};
            window.history.pushState(state, "Title", url);
        },
        error: function (XHR, status, error) {
            //..
        }
    });

});
```